# Select row with maximum value

Tags: mysql, db2

I have one table `T1` with the below columns

```
C1  SeqNo   C2  ID 

1   1       10  abc
1   1       20  xyz
1   1       30  mn0
1   2       10  123
1   3       10  abc
1   3       20  xyz
2   1       10  a1c
2   2       10  x1z
2   2       20  m10
2   2       30  1k3
2   3       10  a1c
2   3       20  x1z
```

I have to select `ID` where `SeqNo` is max and `C2` is max of the max `seqNo` for each distinct value of C1

Result should be:

```
1    3    20    xyz
2    3    20    x1z
```

If anyone can help please

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql` and `db2`?

Comment: ORDER BY seqno DESC, C2 DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: Are you using MySQL or DB2? The answer will be different for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a GROUP BY clause with the MAX aggregate function:

`SELECT id, MAX(rev)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id`
...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT C1, SeqNo, MAX(C2), ID
  FROM T1
 WHERE C1 = 1
 GROUP BY SeqNo
 ORDER BY SeqNo DESC
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

in db2

```
select C1, ID, Max(SeqNo) as SeqNo, Max(C2) as C2
from yourtable
where C1=1
group by C1, ID
order by 3 desc, 4 desc, 2 desc
fetch first rows only
```

Answer (score 0):

other solution in DB2

```
select * from (
select f1.*, rownumber() over(order by SeqNo desc, C2 desc, ID desc) rang
from yourtable f1 where f1.C1=1
) tmp where tmp.rang=1
```